# Unexpected behavior using negative lookaheads in R

Tags: regex, r

Quick question: can anyone tell me why

```
grepl('p(?!q)', 'pq', perl = TRUE)
```

is `FALSE`

but

```
grepl('p(?!p)', 'pp', perl = TRUE)
```

is `TRUE`?

Shouldn't the exact same logic apply? How would I use a negative lookahead to match with a string that contains a "p" that is NOT followed by another "p"?

Comment: `p(?!p)`, is the regex for matching `p` which is not followed by another `p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because with `(?!p)` it will still match because of the end of string position. To correct the lookahead, you need to assert that neither a "p" or the position at the end of the string follows.

```
grepl('p(?!p|$)', 'pp', perl = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE
```

Lookahead is not really needed here either, you can use a negated character class:

```
grepl('p[^p]', c('pp', 'ppp', 'pq'))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Same logic not allowing "q" to follow:

```
grepl('p[^q]', c('pp', 'ppp', 'pq'))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Clear explanation with code for a solution included. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
grepl('p(?!q)', 'pq', perl = TRUE)
```

here there is a single `p`, so it checks that single `p` only. Checks for that single p is not followed by `q`. But it fails since, `p` is followed by `q`. Since it not finds a match, it returns `FALSE`

```
grepl('p(?!p)', 'pp', perl = TRUE)
```

Here it checks for the first `p`. It fails, since the first `p` is followed by another `p`. But when it checks for the second `p`, condition becomes true since the second `p` is not followed by `p`. Because it finds atleast one match, this returns `TRUE` .

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, Avinash. I ended up selecting hwnd's only because he provided code that fixed the problem I was having. Both really useful answers.

Comment: they were both great answers, thank you again for your time. I'd accept both if I could. hwnd answered the first question (though with less detail than you) and also provided an answer to "How would I use a negative lookahead to match with a string that contains a "p" that is NOT followed by another "p"? "